# Which file in Android system represents the identity of phone?

Tags: android

I have root access and want to change the identity of phone in order to make the Software Provider treat this phone as a new one. 
So do you know which file or maybe files in Android system represent the identity of phone that software may read to determine this is a new customer or old one?
Thanks, hope I made clear about the question.

Comment: Identity of phone is IMEI,you cannt change it.Which identity you want to change.

Comment: Yes, in the following answers, I mean Android ID, which need root access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Android ID (It can be altered on rooted phone)

Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

Comment: I'm using BlueStacks simulation on Windows to test the software, is there a way to change this ANDROID_ID without uninstall/reinstall the BlueStacks(That triggers generating a new ID).

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Settings.Secure class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html), and try to get the [Android_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID). Here's a snippet from my own code:

```
String android_id = Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Your class have to extend Activity otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: Thanks, do I need the root access to set a new ANDROID_ID back to system? I'm using BlueStacks simulation on Windows to test the software, is there a way to change this ANDROID_ID without uninstall/reinstall the BlueStacks(That triggers generating a new ID).

Comment: Sorry but it not possible to change a Android_id, why do you want to change it?

Comment: there are a few games out there that use the Android ID to determine if we are using multiple accounts. To cheat this I want to change the it, it seems there is a way but need root access, I'll keep on trying.

Comment: Android_ID: "A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated on the device's first boot and should remain constant for the lifetime of the device". It might change when you factory reset your device but it is not possible to change it manually

Comment: It can. Please root the phone and search Android ID Changer in Google Play

Comment: You don't want to do that, many other apps will not work correctly